# powershell split multiple lines

Tags: powershell, split

```
$vn = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name mynet
$vn.Subnets | Select Name, AddressPrefix,id | sort AddressPrefix
```

I am running this and get...

[image: script output]

How may I list `resourcegroup` name which is in id?

I tried:

```
split "id.Split("/")[4]"
```

but get error:

> Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'

Comment: Indexes start a zero.  Use "id.Split("/")[3]"

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I tried the above and works for me.  I set the output from your Subnets filter to $subnets, then did $subnets.id.Split("/")[4]  -  That worked fine.  Please update your questions with the full code.  You never show where you are using "id", which by itself is not correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks all!
I formatted it.
````
 $subnets.id.Split("/")[4]  
`````
only return first line. I have 7 lines

Answer (score 0):

Save subnets in variable. Expand the ID property of the variable and iterate over each line, splitting on the fourth forward slash containing the resource group.

```
$vn = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name mynet
$subnets = $vn.Subnets | Select Name, AddressPrefix,id | sort AddressPrefix
$subnets.id | ForEach-Object {$_.split("/")[4]}
```